# websites mobile view isn't resizing

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, materialize

I'm writing a [blog](http://roconnor.gitlab.io) using Materialize, and it looks OK (to me anyway, but that might be biased :).

The only problem is, it looks OK on a desktop. When I visit it on mobile view, nothing is zoomed to fit the screen and it's all tiny. It looks OK when I zoom in manually.

How do I fix this? It's so bad I can't read some stuff on my phone. Just to make sure, I've tested it on another phone and also Chrome's phone simulator. What's going off? The source is [here](http://gitlab.com/roconnor/roconnor.gitlab.io). I'd post some code, but I have no idea where (if anywhere) this issue originates from.

Comment: without seeing the head of your document it's only a guess, but have you added the viewport meta tag??

Comment: @Aaron I'm such an idiot -.- Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your code, should fix it

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Apologies, sorted now!